# How to regex square brackets "[]" in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, escaping

Here's the regex:

```
((([a-z])*Map|map)\\[((MapFields::([a-z]|[A-Z])*)|(([a-z]|[A-Z])*))|("([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|_)*")*\\]( )*=( )*([a-z]|[A-Z])*;)
```

and these are my test cases:

- map[MapFields::abCd] = abCd;
- myMap[MapFields::abCd] = abCd;
- map[abCd] = AbCd;
- map[AbCd] = abCd;
- map[AbCd] = abCd;
- myMap[AbCd] = abCd;
- map["AB123"]=abCd;
- map["AB_CD"]=abCd;
- map["AB_CD"]=abCd;

And this works fine here: https://regexr.com

But, when I try to validate my cases using C++11 regex.h. I get invalid matches. I've figured out that it's because of square brackets that I need to escape.

Here's the C++ code,

```
    string data[10] = {
        //array of cases
    };

    try {
    regex rgx(regex string);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
        if ( regex_match(data[i], rgx) ) {
            cout << "string literal matched\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "string literal unmatched\n";
        }
    }
    }
    catch ( exception ex ) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
```

How may I escape the square brackets, so my code can work fine.

Thanks :)

Comment: Unless you use *raw* [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) you need to escape the escape as well, because `\[` is not a valid [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried that too. Program stopped to throw std::regex_error but still mismatches occur. I replaced that "[" matching part with "(.{1})", but still no luck :(

Comment: "C++11 regex.h" ? Do you mean C++11 <regex> or POSIX <regex.h>? It looks like your code is using the former... Using ".h" on standard C++ includes is non-standard and won't work on all platforms/compilers (i.e. in this case, anything that supports POSIX regex).

Comment: `[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|_` can simply be `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Work as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4500e196631feef6)

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, your solution is working as expected. But when I compiled the same code on my VM, it's giving me regex_error.
g++ version: 4.8.5, maybe there's some issue with the version.

Comment: we already have gcc version 9, version 4.8.5 seems old.

Answer (score 0):

After simplification, you might do:

```
int main()
{
    std::string data[] = {
        "map[MapFields::abCd] = abCd;",
        "myMap[MapFields::abCd] = abCd;",
        "map[abCd] = AbCd;",
        "map[AbCd] = abCd;",
        "map[AbCd] = abCd;",
        "myMap[AbCd] = abCd;",
        "map[\"AB123\"]=abCd;",
        "map[\"AB_CD\"]=abCd;",
        "map[\"AB_CD\"]=abCd;"
    };

    try {
        std::regex rgx(R"(((?:[a-z])*Map|map)\[(MapFields::[a-zA-Z]*|[a-zA-Z]*|"[a-zA-Z0-9_]*")\]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z]*);)");

        for (const auto& s : data) {
            std::smatch res;
            if (std::regex_match(s, res, rgx) ) {
                std::cout << s << " [matched]\n";
                for (auto e : res) {
                    std::cout << e << std::endl; // Display matched groups
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << s << " [unmatched]\n";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b46af1177a934455)